How to clear GPU memory in Google Collab after training a model
I am currently trying to do cross-validation with Llama-3 LLM in Google Collab, and I am facing with the issue that the GPU memory runs out way before I am able to finish my experiments. My code is the following:
I have this function to clear the memory:
from GPUtil import showUtilization as gpu_usage
from numba import cuda
import gc
from accelerate import Accelerator

accelerator = Accelerator()

def free_gpu_cache():
  print('Initial GPU Usage')
  gpu_usage()

  gc.collect()
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  accelerator.free_memory()

  cuda.select_device(0)
  cuda.close()
  cuda.select_device(0)

  print("GPU Usage after emptying the cache")
  gpu_usage()

And this is the main code that I am using:
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
    training_data, test_data = data['text'][train_index], data['text'][test_index]

    training_data = Dataset.from_pandas(training_data.to_frame().reset_index())
    test_data = Dataset.from_pandas(test_data.to_frame().reset_index())

    
    free_gpu_cache()

    # model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name,
                                                device_map='auto',
                                                quantization_config=bnb_config,
                                                token = access_token)

    model.config.use_cache = False
    model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

    trainer = SFTTrainer(
      model = model,
      train_dataset = training_data,
      peft_config = lora_config,
      dataset_text_field = 'text',
      max_seq_length = 30,
      tokenizer = tokenizer,
      args = training_arguments,
      packing = True
    )

    trainer.train()

Even though I have the function to clear the memory, I am getting the following error in the second iteration:

ValueError: Some modules are dispatched on the CPU or the disk. Make sure you have enough GPU RAM to fit the quantized model.

I have tried to clear the memory with the funciont showed above, but that did not work.
I have also tried with this:
import gc
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

but it did not work either.
I don't know what else to do

Im not completely sure if this is right, so your might have to wait for someone else to answer. But I believe that "refreshing google colabs" ram  wont work because colab gains money from, 1. limit ram access, 2. paid access to better GPU's.
